# Is it possible to escape a character inside a handlebar?

Tags: javascript, html, json, handlebars.js, templating

I would like to be able to insert a comma inside handlabars.js, for example: {{ JOURNAL \, }} rendering a comma for each item that exists, so there won't be nonsense commas due to a non existing key-value pair. Thank you all!

```
{{#each items}}
 <button class="accordion-button"
     {{#if (equals type "article")}}  {{AUTHOR}} {{TITLE}} {{JOURNAL}}, {{VOLUME}}({{NUMBER}})  {{MONTH}} {{YEAR}}                        {{/if}}
 </button>    
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `JOURNAL` exists. Then include it and a trailing comma only if it does.

```
{{#if JOURNAL}}{{JOURNAL}}, {{/if}}
```

You can also create your own custom helper:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifExistAddComma', function (str) {
    return str === undefined ? '' : `${str}, `;
})
```

```
{{ifExistAddComma JOURNAL}}
```

See [playground](https://handlebarsjs.com/playground.html#format=1&currentExample=%7B%22template%22%3A%22%7B%7BifExistAddComma%20NOT_JOURNAL%7D%7D%20%7B%7BifExistAddComma%20JOURNAL%7D%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22partials%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22input%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20JOURNAL%3A%20%5C%22foo%5C%22%2C%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22output%22%3A%22%20foo%2C%20%5Cn%22%2C%22preparationScript%22%3A%22Handlebars.registerHelper(%27ifExistAddComma%27%2C%20function%20(str)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20str%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%20%3F%20%27%27%20%3A%20%60%24%7Bstr%7D%2C%20%60%3B%5Cn%7D)%5Cn%22%2C%22handlebarsVersion%22%3A%224.7.7%22%7D)

**Edit:** You can write a more complex (but also more general) custom helper for joining any number of arguments with a custom deliminator:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('join', function (delim, ...args) {
  args.pop() // remove meta information
  return args
    .filter(arg => arg !== undefined) // filter out undefined properties
    .join(delim);
})
```

```
{{join ', ' AUTHOR TITLE JOURNAL (join '' VOLUME '(' NUMBER ')') MONTH YEAR}}
```

```
author, title, journal, volume(number), month, year
```

See [playground](https://handlebarsjs.com/playground.html#format=1&currentExample=%7B%22template%22%3A%22%7B%7Bjoin%20%27%2C%20%27%20AUTHOR%20TITLE%20JOURNAL%20(join%20%27%27%20VOLUME%20%27(%27%20NUMBER%20%27)%27)%20MONTH%20YEAR%7D%7D%22%2C%22partials%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22input%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20JOURNAL%3A%20%5C%22journal%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20AUTHOR%3A%20%27author%27%2C%5Cn%20%20TITLE%3A%20%27title%27%2C%5Cn%20%20VOLUME%3A%20%27volume%27%2C%5Cn%20%20NUMBER%3A%20%27number%27%2C%5Cn%20%20MONTH%3A%20%27month%27%2C%5Cn%20%20YEAR%3A%20%27year%27%2C%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22output%22%3A%22author%2C%20title%2C%20journal%2C%20volume(number)%2C%20month%2C%20year%22%2C%22preparationScript%22%3A%22Handlebars.registerHelper(%27join%27%2C%20function%20(delim%2C%20...args)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20args.pop()%3B%20%2F%2F%20remove%20meta%20information%5Cn%20%20return%20args%5Cn%20%20%5Ct.filter(arg%20%3D%3E%20arg%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%2F%2F%20filter%20out%20undefined%20properties%5Cn%20%20%20%20.join(delim)%3B%5Cn%7D)%3B%5Cn%22%2C%22handlebarsVersion%22%3A%224.7.7%22%7D)

Comment: I was going to answer, Thanks :+1

Comment: The only problem with this is that the code will be bloated If I do it for each {{AUTHOR}} {{TITLE}} {{JOURNAL}}, {{VOLUME}}({{NUMBER}})  {{MONTH}} {{YEAR}}, it will get massive, but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @AlexandruFilipescu you can also use a custom helper.

Comment: You are incredible Olian, thank you!!

Comment: I found out that there is a problem regarding the last element shown, it will also have a comma, is there any way to check it being the last item? Thank you.

Comment: @AlexandruFilipescu see my latest edit