# (Handlebar.JS)Best way to output different templates for items with certain keys

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, templating, client-side-templating

I am stuck already with this problem for more than a day, the idea is that would like somehow to also add a comma between each of the items and a full stop at the end.

```
        {{#each items}}
         <button class="accordion-button"
           {{#if (equals type "article")}}  {{AUTHOR}} {{TITLE}} {{JOURNAL}} {{VOLUME}}({{NUMBER}})                       {{/if}}
           {{#if (equals type "book")}} {{AUTHOR}} {{EDITOR}} {{BOOKTITLE}} {{/if}}
         </button>    
        {{/each}}
```

I was suggested to add a custom helper for each handlebar and it worked partially as I am not able to find the last element and add a full stop to it. Is there any way to get all the existing handlebars between the {if}........{/if} statement and loop through them?

One .json entry:

```
    {
    "key": "ACM94b",
    "type": "article",
    "AUTHOR": "Adam",
    "INSTITUTION": "ACM",
    "JOURNAL": "Communications of the ACM",
    "KEYWORDS": "scglib",
    "MONTH": "May",
    "NUMBER": "5",
    "TITLE": "Reverse Engineering",
    "VOLUME": "37",
    "YEAR": "1994"
},
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I've already answered this on your previous question. See the latest update to the accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70053831/6224823

Comment: I've seen it but I found out that It is not exactly working because I can't find out the last existing item to put a full stop instead of a comma, thank you for helping me anyway!!

Comment: Are you sure you've looked at the latest edit? `{{join ', ' AUTHOR TITLE JOURNAL (join '' VOLUME '(' NUMBER ')') MONTH YEAR}}` ?

Comment: Oh god I haven't seen it, I will look at it right now, how can I even thank you for the effort?

Comment: Keep learning and keep programming. That's payment enough :)

Comment: You saved me It works!, I was stuck for so long, thanks Olian! If you are in Bern, Switzerland, let me know! Do you have social media?

Comment: Handlebars _does_ provide a way to identify the last element in an array - the [`@last` data-variable](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#last). For your use-case, the code solution could be as simple as adding: `{{#if @last}}.{{else}},{{/if}}`.

Comment: But how would I have to wrap it around my code: {{AUTHOR}} {{TITLE}} {{JOURNAL}}
individually for each one? Thank you!

Comment: It would go at the bottom of your `#each` loop. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/q82v9rj6/ (Note that I have used a `~` in the `#if` to remove whitespace - see: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#whitespace-control

Comment: I was looking to separate each field AUTHOR, TITLE, JOURNAL. with a comma all the buttons separated by commas, but thank you!!